Exactness of the sequence $0\rightarrow\mathbb{Z}_p\xrightarrow{p^n}\mathbb{Z}_p\xrightarrow{\varepsilon_n} A_n\rightarrow 0$
On page 12 of the book A Course in Arithmetic by Serre, the author proves that the sequence $0\rightarrow\mathbb{Z}_p\xrightarrow{p^n}\mathbb{Z}_p\xrightarrow{\varepsilon_n} A_n\rightarrow 0$ is exact, where $\varepsilon_n:\mathbb{Z}_p\rightarrow A_n$ ($A_n=\mathbb{Z}/p^n\mathbb{Z}$) maps to the $n$-th component of a $p$-adic integer. Below I copy (word for word as in the original text) the part of the proof where the author verifies $\ker\varepsilon_n= p^n\mathbb{Z}_p$:

It is clear that the kernel of $\varepsilon_n$ contains $p^n \mathbb{Z}_p$; conversely, if $x = (x_m)$ belongs to $\ker (\varepsilon_m)$, one has $x_m \equiv 0 \ (\text{mod} \ p^n)$ for all $m \geqslant n$ which means that there exists a well defined element $y_{m-n}$ of $A_{m-n}$ such that its image under the isomorphism $A_{m-n} \to p^n \mathbb{Z} / p^m \mathbb{Z} \subset A_m$ satisfies $x_m = p^n y_{m-n}$. The $y_i$ define an element $y$ of $\mathbb{Z}_p = \varprojlim A_i$, and one checks immediately that $p^n y = x$, which proves the proposition.

I would like help to understand this argument. Up to the part where we obtain the equation $x_m = p^n y_{m-n}$, I understand. We can produce the elements $y_{1},...,y_{m-1}$, but what about the elements $y_m, y_{m+1}, y_{m+2},...$? Are they all equal to $y_{m-1}$ (considering that $A_{m+k}$ contains a copy of $A_{m-1}$ for $k \geqslant 0$, thus a copy of $y_{m-1}$)? If not, what are the entries $y_i$ for $i \geqslant m$? My other question is how to verify that the element $(y_n)$ thus produced is, indeed, an element of $\mathbb{Z}_p$, that is, showing that $\phi_{n+1}(y_{n+1}) = y_n$ for all $n \geqslant 1$ ($\phi_{n+1}: A_{n+1} \rightarrow A_{n}$ are the homomorphisms considered in the projective system).
Below is a print of the mentioned paragraph:



In the first paragraph, you probably mean $A_n=\mathbb Z/p^n\mathbb Z$.

@KentaS Yes, I made the correction. Thanks.

In the first sentence of the copied text, should it be "belongs to $\mathrm{ker}(\epsilon_{\color{red}{n}})$"?

Because that kind of solves the issue: It is $n$ that is fixed here, and $m$ can be any number $\ge n$, so we have all $y_0, y_1, y_2, ...$.

@TorstenSchoeneberg In fact, in the original excerpt from the book we actually have $\ker(\varepsilon_m)$. I included a screenshot of the text in the question. Indeed, if it is just a typographical error, then everything fits together.

In the first sentence of the copied text, it should be "belongs to ker $\left(\epsilon_n\right.$ )".It might be just a typographical error.
And the map $\phi_{n+1}:\mathbb{Z} / P^{n+1} \rightarrow \mathbb{Z} / P^n \mathbb{Z}$ is $\quad x \mapsto x \bmod p^n$.
$x_k=0$ for all $k<n$ because $\phi_{k+1}(0)=0$.
